# How to pass variable to next middleware from gridfs storage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer-gridfs-storage

Below is my code where i authenticate if user is admin and then upload a file:

```
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: process.env.MONGO_URI,
  file: async (req, file) => {
    async function authenticate() {
      const { authorization } = req.headers;
      if (authorization && authorization.startsWith("Bearer")) {
        try {
          const token = authorization.split(" ")[1];
          const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
          const user = await Auth.findById(decoded.id);
          if (user.admin !== true) {
            throw new Error("Not Authorized") // not working
            // res.status(400).json({message:"Not Authorized"}) //gives error res is not defined
            req.message = "Not Authorized";
          }
        } catch (error) {
          req.message = "Token Error";
        }
      } else {
        req.message = "No Token";
      }
    }
    try{
      await authenticate();
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       const fileInfo = {
        filename: id,
        bucketName: "books",
       };
       resolve(fileInfo);
     });
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage,
});

module.exports = {
  upload,
};
```

I get the following error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:370:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:573:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\Programs\VS Code\Web Development\lmsbackend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\Programs\VS Code\Web Development\lmsbackend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\Programs\VS Code\Web Development\lmsbackend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
    at errorHandler (D:\Programs\VS Code\Web Development\lmsbackend\middleware\errorMiddleware.js:4:7)
    at Layer.handle_error (D:\Programs\VS Code\Web Development\lmsbackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\Programs\VS Code\Web Development\lmsbackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:326:13)
    at D:\Programs\VS Code\Web Development\lmsbackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (D:\Programs\VS Code\Web Development\lmsbackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
```

I understood this error. I could work around this error if i had `res` available but i do not have `res` inside my gridfs storage.

I want to authenticate the user and stop execution if user is not admin. But `throw new Error()` is not working and `break` is also not accessible.

Also if someone could tell me a technique through which i could pass the error messages to the next middleware which helps me throws them would be helpful.

I tried different ways to pass variable to next middleware as well as stop execution by different ways but i could not. Thanks in advance.